# Iterating a variable that includes a letter and a number (q1)

Tags: php

Im fairly new to coding...

i want to be able to change a PHP variable from holding a value of 'q1' to 'q2', 'q3' and so on in a loop.

q1 ect relates to a question id in a database, the end result im hoping to be able to achieve is to increase the qnumber so that the next questions answers get recorded for the correct question number.

Cheers

Comment: Just imagine you ask this your own. Howe would you do it? Put that idea as code into your question. That will greatly improve your question! Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: If the Q numbers are already in the database and somebody is answering a question you should already know the Q number to use, no? Also, if they are in the database and you are generating then there is a possibility for trouble. Like if you delete Q2 and there's no replacement (I'm suppositionising, more data would be useful!)

Comment: It is a good idea to link some of the code you have tried, to help other's help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=1; $i<=$limit; $i++) {
  $var = 'q'.$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code:

```
$var = "q"; 
$i = 1;
for $i to N-1 
  $var.$i//do whatever. $var.i concatenates.
```